# How to get the image path stored in Local Azure storage emulator

Tags: azure, cloud-storage

Here i am using Local azure storage emulator. I am able to store the images in the blob storage.  I connected the azure storage emulator to my local DB, so i am able to see the local path of image in the data base. Here i need to get the path in the code and need to save in another table.
 here is the code. I need to return local image path.

```
  public static CloudBlockBlob getAzureStorage(string imageName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imageName);
        return blockBlob;
    }

  public static string uploadToAzure(Image img, CloudBlockBlob blockBlob)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
        return String.Format("http://{0}{1}", blockBlob.Uri.DnsSafeHost, blockBlob.Uri.AbsolutePath);
    }
```

Comment: I got the answer for the question.                             container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container });
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for the question.  set the permission to public.T

```
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess =         BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container });
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
```